# 'npm ERR! 404 Not Found: async-validator' while installing Element-UI

Tags: npm, installation, element-ui

I keep getting

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: async-validator@~1.8.1
```

while trying to install Element-UI. Tried installing async-validator through npm and got the same error, tried reinstalling Node, ...

```
node v10.2.1
npm 6.1.0
```

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
I followed the first link MantasPtr commented and was able to install async validator like so:

```
npm install https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator/archive/1.8.2.tar.gz
```

Comment: Try `npm install async-validator@latest`

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify the version code while installing a new version of library using npm. It might download the order version of that library

Specify the library name as it is to install the latest version or specify @latest

> npm install async-validator --save

or

> npm install async-validator@latest --save

Answer (score 0):

May be, this is a temporary solution:
npm install https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator/archive/1.8.1.tar.gz

if you try to load npm install https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator/archive/1.8.2.tar.gz in a browser, you will see {"error":"Not found"} as a result.

but https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator/archive/1.8.1.tar.gz will be found. So I work with an older version and will look for an update later.